# Is it better to follow some structure or just write following intuition

Tags: structure, screenwriting

I have a plot in mind without any details. I am planning to write it down as a story and then a screenplay, without any background in writing or reading books but just watching movies. When going through online articles its seen that following certain structures for plots is useful and is widely followed by many.  One example is [this](http://2012.scriptfrenzy.org/node/402156).

Now I wonder if I should just write what comes to my mind or plan and do some homework and build the story methodologically. What usually works good in writing?

PS:I'll provide a rough synopsis on request if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is best to **find your story** following your *intuition*, then *structure* it to **write your story**.

Creativity and originality flow best if unimpeded, so don't hinder your ideas by attempting to force them into a structure when you are at the stage of developing your story idea. But stories read better if they are not confusing; they are more satisfying, if they have rhythm and a certain builtup and release of tension; so carve out their inherent structure, clarify, simplify, and polish, when you're at the writing strage.

Comment: ok, so its like write a rough copy first with whatever comes to mind, then structure and modify it until we are satisfied?

Comment: That is how many authors do it. There are of course many variations, but the message I wanted to convey is: both are important, and you need to find the right kind of balance that works for you. Read around a bit how authors work, experiment with different approaches, and with time your own personal method will crystalize. The important part is to have no fear of failure, and to try all kinds of things. Like learning to walk: you don't just stand and walk, you'll have to find out how it works for you.

Comment: @what Excellent concise bit of advice, in that first sentence of your answer!